# AoO and Touch spells on Allies

Tags: pathfinder-1e, touch-attacks

We play a mainly pathfinder game (occassional and as time goes on fewer feats from 3.5) and we still keep coming across things that have changed between 3.5 and pathfinder.

Casting a spell triggers an AoO (unless you cast on the defensive) but does touching an ally to deliver the spell trigger as well? A pathfinder RAW answer would be good. I am sure in 3.5 it did but cannot find anything in pathfinder.

I have found something that says if I use a full round action to touch upto 6 ally it does trigger (if you can fit an enermy in that ruck) but how about just a standard action and just one.

cheers

Comment: Touch attacks never provoked, in 3.5 or *Pathfinder*. Only actually casting the spell did. *Ranged* touch attacks would have, but only because *all* ranged attacks do, the fact that it's a touch attack has nothing to do with it.

Comment: But what about casting a cure spell on the defensive, then touching an ally with the cure whilst you are both stood in front of a monster that threatens you both?

Answer (score 5):

**No, touching an ally does not provoke AoO.**

[Pathfinder SRD, Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat) (emphasis mine):

> "Armed" Unarmed Attacks: Sometimes a character's or creature's unarmed attack counts as an armed attack. A monk, a character with the Improved Unarmed Strike feat, **a spellcaster delivering a touch attack spell**, and a creature with natural physical weapons all **count as being armed**

Armed melee attacks do not provoke an AoO.

This is explicitly repeated in *Touch spells in combat section*:

> Touch Attacks: Touching an opponent with a touch spell is considered to be an armed attack and therefore does not provoke attacks of opportunity. The act of casting a spell, however, does provoke an attack of opportunity.

The exception to this is a full-round action to touch 6 allies, which always provokes an AoO.

Comment: Their wording is bad but a Touch attack on an ally allows the ally for a AoO on you, but we simply assume he never takes it.

Comment: @MrJinPengyou Actually it specifically says that no, a Touch Attack doesn't allow for a AoO.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I read too fast I guess

Comment: @MrJinPengyou You could read the second rule as applying to opponents only, but that may be an oversight as you don't normally even make an attack roll to touch allies.

Comment: Is a non-attack spell delivered by touch considered a touch "attack"?

Comment: The *Touch Attacks* excerpt does not differentiate between harmful and beneficial spells for the purpose of delivering a touch spell. Therefore, yes.

Comment: @JeorMattan It does specifically call out “opponent,” though. That could be an oversight, or it could be an example of _exception proves the rule._