# Do touch-range spells create an attack of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, opportunity-attack, touch-attacks

If I cast a touch spell, such as *Bull Strength*, does it provoke an Attack of Opportunity? I realize that touch attack spells do not, but is that still the case if I'm not attacking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**

As per [PRD](http://paizo.com/prd/combat.html) combat chapter, casting a spell provokes an attack of opportunity. There is no exception for touch range spells.

As for the touch attacks with a spell, it is the act of attacking itself which doesn't provoke an AoO; the act of casting still does.

You may find [these](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26313/attack-of-opportunity-spell-casting) [three](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/24866/aoo-and-touch-spells-on-allies) [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22944/how-do-touch-spells-work-in-pathfinder) relevant to yours.